# Appending metadata to a newly created image via php?

Tags: php, metadata, iptc

I have php script that creates a temporary watermark image for users that are not logged in.  The original image contains IPTC (metadata) information that I would like to retain, however, when the watermark is applied and imagejpeg is called, all metadata is removed.

Any ideas how I can maintain the metadata or re-apply metadata after imagejpeg gets called?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just what the [iptcparse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcparse.php) and [iptcembed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php) functions are for.

Comment: What happens if you var_dump() the results of iptcparse(), as in the example on the PHP.net example?

Comment: I just found that my temporary image file wasn't being saved properly thanks to a typo.  So the IPTC information was attempting to be written to a file with size 0.

Fixed and working fine now, thanks!